# Make numbers in table bold w/o changing width

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, bold

I want to highlight some numbers in a table using `\bf{}`. However, the bold numbers also get wider but I want them to neatly line up with the rest. How can I avoid this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I am sure there is an exact question on this site about generating bold text using the same horizontal space, but haven't found it yet...

Comment: What typeface are you using? Is it the default Computer Modern?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the default typeface.

Comment: This is apparently known as  known "Duplexing" and is a important feature of "Tabular Figures" (as contrasted to "Proportional Figures" used outside of tables). Maybe these keywords should be added to the question as this doesn't show up in google.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use "non extended bold face":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\bftab}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
Class & Value \\
\midrule
A & 10 \\
B & 12 \\
C & \bftab 13 \\
D & 11 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note. From your question I gather that you're using `\bf{13}` or something like that. It's wrong for two reasons:

1. `\bf` is an obsolete command;
2. it is *not* a command with argument.

Use `\textbf{13}` or `{\bfseries 13}` (the former is preferred for single snippets of boldface text, the latter is for longer passages or in the definition of environments).

Comment: Note that whether this works seems to depend on the font and the fontsize. E.g. scriptsize cmr `b` is too narrow (while `bx` is still too wide, and `bsx` doesn't exist).

Comment: what if I want to use bold for multiple chunks of text? For example, `\bftab 0.673 $\pm$ 0.017` only makes 0.017 bold. While `{\bftab 0.673 $\pm$ 0.017}` works but alters the alignment of the cell.

Comment: @LucaClissa You should use `siunitx` features, in this case those related to uncertainty.

Comment: @egreg Can you elaborate more? I can open a new post if you think it's better

Comment: @LucaClissa Did you look for “uncertainty” in the manual of `siunitx`?

Comment: @egreg I tried to, but it didn't help. Anyway I found out I can use `\bftab` in conjunction with `detect-weight` option to make the whole thing (number \pm uncertainty) bold. Specifically, I used something like `\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{5}{S[detect-weight]} @{}}` in the column definition and then `bftab` in the cell I wanted to make bold.